# WPF MVVM Grid With Button Column

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am following the  MVVM pattern. I have a grid with few columns one column having Button in it . Clicking on button i want to open dialog box which is expected to display data related to that particular row in which button was clicked. But the problem is with binding , as i am unable to bind the control with viewmodel.

```
<Button  Command="{Binding Path=ParentRow.DataContext, 
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=Default}" 
         lib:Event.Binding="Click.[**NameOfViewModelMethod**]" >                                      
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, if your `Button` is inside a `Grid` with a defined `DataContext` you don't need to set the `Path` like `Path=ParentRow.DataContext`.

Your `Command` binding should be like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding YourVMICommand"} />
```

You have to define a `public ICommand` in your VM and then bind it to the button.

Answer (score -1):

you don't show all of your code and context but it should work like this 
i assume you are in a usercontrol caling parent datacontext ...
(exemple with listview):

```
<ListView   ItemsSource="{Binding listFromDataContext, IsAsync=True}" Margin="3,51,0,10"    >

<ListView.ItemTemplate >
<DataTemplate>
<grid>
 <Button   Command="{Binding DataContext.MyMethode, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type controls:thisUserControl}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"   />
</grid>
</DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate >
</ListView>
```

then in model

```
      private ICommand _MyMethode;
            public ICommand MyMethode
            {
                get
                {
                    return _MyMethode ?? (_MyMethode = new CommandHandler<MyModel.item>(x => showMessage(x), _canExecute));
                }
            }

public void showMessage(MyModel.item x)
{
MessageBox.Show(x.Info);
}
```

Comment: Hi Zwan..  Thanks you for reply ... it would be great if you can provide little more code.